# get key of element in array which is inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have array which has key and inside an object. Trying to get the key of element which is inside the array.

when I search for 4512 I should get key as eggs_code.

```js
const items = {
  storeItems: {
    milk_code: [1212, 9898, 1214],
    vegetables_code: [2222, 75674, 8943, 3452],
    eggs_code: [4543, 4512, 1754, 9090]
  }
}
```

```js
if (items.storeItems.includes(4512)) {
  const type = Object.keys(items(4512);
  console.log(type);
}
```

Comment: If the search value appears in multiple arrays, what should be returned? The first key? Last key? All matches?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the key / value pairs of `storeItems`, searching the values to return the key

```js
const findKey = (obj, search) => {
  for (let [ key, val ] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (val.includes(search)) return key
  }
  return null
}

const items = {
  storeItems: {
    milk_code: [1212, 9898, 1214],
    vegetables_code: [2222, 75674, 8943, 3452],
    eggs_code: [4543, 4512, 1754, 9090]
  }
}

console.info(findKey(items.storeItems, 4512))
```

This will return the first key found (in definition order) with a matching value.

---

If the value can appear in multiple values and you want to return all matches, you can use a simple *filter*

```js
const findKeys = (obj, search) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key].includes(search))
}

const items = {
  storeItems: {
    milk_code: [1212, 9898, 1214, 4512], // added 4512 here
    vegetables_code: [2222, 75674, 8943, 3452],
    eggs_code: [4543, 4512, 1754, 9090]
  }
}

console.info(findKeys(items.storeItems, 4512))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```js
const search_q = 4512;
let k = null;

const items = {
  storeItems: {
    milk_code: [1212, 9898, 1214],
    vegetables_code: [2222, 75674, 8943, 3452],
    eggs_code: [4543, 4512, 1754, 9090]
  }
}

Object.keys(items.storeItems).forEach(item => {
  if(items.storeItems[item].includes(search_q))
      k = item;
})

console.log(k)
```

Comment: One problem with this...It will continue to iterate the keys even after it finds a match. This will result in the last key with a match. If OP wants the first, this is a problem.

Comment: It's only a problem if the OP does, indeed, want the first occurrence. Since that question is open-ended, I didn't see a problem returning the last occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries` and `find` method

```js
const items = {
  storeItems: {
    milk_code: [1212, 9898, 1214],
    vegetables_code: [2222, 75674, 8943, 3452],
    eggs_code: [4543, 4512, 1754, 9090],
  },
};

const getKey = (obj, val) =>
  Object.entries(obj)
    .find(([key, arr]) => arr.includes(val))
    ?.shift();
    
    
console.log(getKey(items.storeItems, 4512));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a little function to do it for you. This function matches the first time the code is found.

```js
const items = {
  store_items: {
    milk_code: [1212, 9898, 1214],
    vegetables_code: [2222, 75674, 8943, 3452],
    eggs_code: [4543, 4512, 1754, 9090]
  }
}

function find_code( code, object ) {
  for( const property in object )
    if( object[property].includes(code) ) return property;
  
  return undefined;
}

console.log( find_code( 4512, items.store_items ) );
console.log( find_code( 1200, items.store_items ) );
console.log( find_code( 8943, items.store_items ) );
```

Note that you are iterating over an `Object`, not an `Array`. You can iterate over an object with `for..of` or `for..in`. I used `for..in`, because that one extracts the property name by default.

[Read more about for..in on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)